# RollingFile not create new log after midnight

Tags: java, maven-3, log4j2

java 1.8

maven 3.5

In pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In my Maven java  project I want to generate new log file every new day (midnight).

So I use `RollingFile` and cron `0 0 0 * * ?`. Here my log4j2.xml

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
    <Property name="patterLayout">%d{[dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} %l %p:%n %m%n</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${patterLayout}"/>-
    </Console>

   
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
                 filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${patterLayout}"/>-
        <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
                <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz"/>
                <IfLastModified age="60d"/>
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
```

But all logs print in **ONE** file app.log.

Here result:

```
[27.11.2021 23:59:05.235] com.myproject.xls2metro2.App.main(App.java:18) TRACE:
 JDK: 1.8.0_202
[27.11.2021 23:59:05.238] com.myproject.xls2metro2.App.main(App.java:33) WARN:
 File path is mandatory

[28.11.2021 00:01:13.347] com.myproject.xls2metro2.App.main(App.java:18) TRACE:
 JDK: 1.8.0_202
[28.11.2021 00:01:13.351] com.myproject.xls2metro2.App.main(App.java:33) WARN:
 File path is mandatory
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, verify that your original configuration doesn't have this hyphen character (probably you have added it accidentally while writing a question)

```
<PatternLayout pattern="${patterLayout}"/>-
```

Also, make sure that your code is wrapped inside the `Configuration` tag (I assume that you have omitted it for the sake of brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
... your code here
</Configuration>
```

At second, your config looks exactly the same as in the [official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) examples, so it should be fine.

But in the documentation stated that:

> The CronTriggeringPolicy triggers rollover based on a cron expression.
> This policy is controlled by a timer and is asynchronous to processing
> log events, ***so it is possible that log events from the previous or
> next time period may appear at the beginning or end of the log file***.
> The filePattern attribute of the Appender should contain a timestamp
> otherwise the target file will be overwritten on each rollover.

So probably, this is your case. Just wait a little longer to verify, that the next logs will be written to a separate file.

Comment: Your advises not help. All logs generate in ONE log file

Comment: @a_subscriber, please, verify which version you are using. It may affect the behavior:
`Since log4j-2.5, a custom delete action can be configured in the DefaultRolloverStrategy to run at rollover. Since 2.8 if no file name is configured then DirectWriteRolloverStrategy will be used instead of DefaultRolloverStrategy. Since log4j-2.9, a custom POSIX file attribute view action can be configured in the DefaultRolloverStrategy to run at rollover, if not defined, inherited POSIX file attribute view from the RollingFileAppender will be applied.`

Comment: log4j-slf4j-impl :  2.13.3